# Gif animation exporting wrong

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export

I made only 1 arrow visible at a time on the PSD but the 2 arrows stay faded but visible when I export as you can see:

[image: Failing export]

Here is my [PSD file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53705840/rarrow.psd).

Comment: Opening the psd file it clearly shows that you have frames that contain the faded arrows. Have you tried deleting those frames?

Comment: The frames were generated by Photoshop for fading effect, there are 3 "main"frames, where there is only 1 arrow

Answer (score 1):

The issue we have here comes from transparency in the original image which can not be preserved on exporting to GIF:

[image]

What we can see is an almost transparent arrow on the right side of the original picture *(left)* presumably left over from a fade effect we may have used. On reducing color depth when converting to GIF this transparency information is lost *(right)*. It was replaced here by white from background. This is because we can only have one single 100% transparent color in a GIF file.

To overcome this we can

- avoid semi-transparent colors in the original image
- or alternatively we may dither the image to allow fake semi-transparency and reduce color depth before we export to GIF (or if available as an option on exporting/converting to GIF).

Answer (score 1):

Your .psd files shows 3 arrows and movement. If you don't want 3 arrows, remove 2 of the arrow layers. If you only want opacity to change, then duplicate one frame, adjust the opacity on the (single) arrow layer, then tween between the 2 frames of your animation:

[image]
[image]

Make certain your first frame is set to "dispose" before tweening.

If you want one arrow moving right to left. Start with frame 1 and the arrow layer on the right. Add frame 2, and then move the arrow layer to the left. Then tween between the 2 frames.

[image]
[image]

If you aren't happy with the build up of the arrow, then you need to alter the little bouncing ball icon on the frames - control-click it and set it to "dispose" so it disposes the previous frames.

[image]
[image]

Beyond this... I don't know what you need since you failed to describe the actual issue.

For all of the above, you only need 1 layer with the arrow, not 3.